# Randomize li items and freeze multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

I need to randomize a list of 5-n li items and set for 1-5 items a specific place, for example, I have

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
6. f

And I want to randomize the last 4 and put on li[0] letter D and on li[2] letter F
Results:

1. **d**
2. **f**
3. c
4. b
5. a
6. e

Here is my code. Where I'm wrong? Thanks!

```
    var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--) {

    if(ul.children.innerHTML == "XXX") {
        ul.appendChild(ul.children[0]);
    }
    if(ul.children.innerHTML == "XXXX") {
        ul.appendChild(ul.children[1]);
    }
    if(ul.children.innerText == "XX") {
        ul.appendChild(ul.children[2]);
    } else {
        ul.appendChild(ul.children[generateRandom(i) | 0]);
    }
}


function generateRandom(i) {
    var num = Math.random() * i | 0;
    return (num === 0 || num === 1 || num === 2) ? generateRandom(i) : num;
}
```

Comment: Randomness is pretty simple, but I'm unclear how logically it is supposed to know to treat *d* and *f* special, given that the list can be N long.

Comment: Math.random returns a float between 0 and 1, it's super unlikely that random * i will be exactly equal to 0, 1 or 2.  Usually folks use `Math.floor(Math.random() * i)`  to return an integer between 0 and i - 1

Comment: I need any strings like "Apple" and "Orange" to go on the selected li position and rest of them randomized

Comment: Ok, *how* do you identify "Apple" and "Orange" as special?  Or for that matter, what rule are you going by to say "any strings like"?  We have to know the logical rules before we can make the code implement those rules.

Comment: Something like if ul.children[i].innerHTML == "apple" append for position [2]

Comment: Ok, so you are specifically checking for the values.

Comment: Yes I'm checking for the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var $test = $('#test');
var $li = $test.children();

while ($li.length > 0) {
  //pick a random li from the variable
  var $next = $li.eq( Math.floor( Math.random() * 10 * $li.length ) % $li.length );
  //move it to the end of ul
  $test.append($next);
  //remove the li from our variable so it won't be found again
  $li = $li.not($next);
}

//move the f to the top, so when we move the d to the top it will be second
$test.prepend($test.children().filter(function(){ return this.innerHTML === 'f'; }));
//move the d to the top
$test.prepend($test.children().filter(function(){ return this.innerHTML === 'd'; }));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="test">
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li>d</li>
  <li>e</li>
  <li>f</li>
  <li>g</li>
  <li>h</li>
  <li>i</li>
  <li>j</li>
  <li>k</li>
</ul>
```